# CakePHP - find custom nested select LEFT JOIN

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How can I do a nested select when doing a find in CakePHP?

Here is a simplified data that I have currently.

```
Listings

id |  title    | content
----------------------
1  | Listing 1 | ...

Media

id        | listing_id | file
----------------------------------
1         | 1          | file 1
2         | 1          | file 2
```

So when I do this.

```
$this->Listing->find('all');
```

This is the output that I get.

```
id |  title    | content | id        | listing_id | file
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Listing 1 | ...     | 1         | 1          | file 1
1  | Listing 1 | ...     | 1         | 1          | file 2
```

And the query is as follow

```
SELECT * FROM `listings` AS `Listing` 
LEFT JOIN `media` AS `Image` ON (`Listing`.`id` = `Image`.`listing_id`)
```

However, I just would love to join it with the first row of the Media table.

Essentially, this is the query that I'm looking for

```
SELECT * FROM `listings` AS `Listing` 
LEFT JOIN `media` AS `Image` ON (`Image`.`id` = (SELECT MIN(`Image`.`id`) FROM `media` AS `Image` WHERE `Listing`.`id` = `Image`.`listing_id`))
```

How can I achieve that query in CakePHP?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using a `hasMany` association with a custom find query.

In your `Listing` model you would do something like this (not tested).

```
 public $hasMany = array(
     'Image'=>array(
         'finderQuery'=>'SELECT MIN(`Image`.`id`) FROM `media` AS `Image` WHERE `Listing`.`id` = `Image`.`listing_id`)'
     )
 );
```

Read more -> [Custom Finder Query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)

Comment: Thanks @Mathew! This didn't quite work for me but it does lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it to work.

```
$this->Listing->find('all', 'contain' => array('Image' => array('conditions' => array(SELECT MIN(`Image`.`id`) FROM `media` AS `Image` WHERE `Listing`.`id` = `Image`.`listing_id`)))));
```